# Class serving data via callbacks

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have recently returned to Visual C++ after a while programming in C where callbacks are much easier.

I have a singleton class which controls 0..* connected devices.
My idea is to create a function in this class which will iterate over the set of
connected devices and publish it via a callback to whatever might require it.

e.g.

```
Singleton class

typedef void (CALLBACK * PortListCallback_t)(ptrConstCComPortInfo_t);
.
.
.

void CCommsMgr::listPorts(PortListCallback_t cb)
{
    PortInfoSetConstIter_t i;
    for (i = m_setPorts.begin(); i != m_setPorts.end(); i++)
    {
        cb(*i);
    }
}
```

In the first instance the consumer is an MFC dialog class which works fine if it's callback is static. However in order to access member data/functions of the dialog class I would need to pass 'this' to the singleton class and have it reflected back.

e.g.

```
Singleton class

typedef void (CALLBACK * PortListCallback_t)(void *, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t);
.
.
.

void CCommsMgr::listPorts(void *pObj, PortListCallback_t cb)
{
    PortInfoSetConstIter_t i;
    for (i = m_setPorts.begin(); i != m_setPorts.end(); i++)
    {
        cb(pObj, *i);
    }
}


Dialog Class

static void CALLBACK getPorts(void *obj, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t port);
.
.
.

void CALLBACK CMFC_iTFTPDlg::getPorts(void *obj, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t port)
{
   CMFC_iTFTPDlg *pThis = (CMFC_iTFTPDlg*)obj;
   // do something with it
}
```

My question - Is there a better way of doing this? Static functions feel like a kludge and I do not want the Singleton class to be constrained by how it might be used.
If I remove the static on getPorts it will not compile. To repeat myself the Singleton class should have no knowledge of it's consumer.

Comment: A combination of `std::function`, `std::bind`, and `std::placeholders`, would probably deliver what you're looking for. All of the above can be researched on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the excellent hints from WhozCraig, this is what I came up with:

```
#include <functional> // std::function, std::bind, std::placeholders
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class ConstCComPortInfo {};

using ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = ConstCComPortInfo*;
using callback_t = void(void*, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t);
using function_t = std::function<callback_t>;

// an example class with a member function to call
class foo {
public:
    foo(const std::string& name) : instance_name(name) {}

    void bar(void* something, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t c) {
        std::cout << "foo::bar(" << instance_name << ") called\n"
                     "void* = " << something << "\n"
                     "ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = " << c << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::string instance_name;
};

// and a free function to call
void free_func(void* something, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t c) {
    std::cout << "free_func_called\n"
                 "void* = " << something << "\n"
                 "ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = " << c << "\n";
}

int main() {
    // some instances of the class
    foo via_bind("called_via_bind");
    foo via_lambda("called_via_lambda");

    ptrConstCComPortInfo_t bork = nullptr; // dummy value

    // a vector of callback subscribers
    std::vector<function_t> subscribers{
        &free_func,
        std::bind(&foo::bar, &via_bind, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2),
        [&via_lambda](void* p, ptrConstCComPortInfo_t c) { via_lambda.bar(p, c); }
    };

    // perform callbacks
    for(auto& cb : subscribers) {
        cb(nullptr, bork);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
free_func_called
void* = 0
ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = 0
foo::bar(called_via_bind) called
void* = 0
ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = 0
foo::bar(called_via_lambda) called
void* = 0
ptrConstCComPortInfo_t = 0
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and it works exactly as I required. Once again sincere thanks to you both.

Comment: @DavidRegan I just realized that I overlooked to demonstrate how to use lambdas in the answer. Added that now.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I will experiment with lambdas. A lot has changed over the last 15 years.

Comment: @DavidRegan It sure has. I think the lambda approach is what most people would go for nowadays. It does look nicer than the `bind` / `placeholders` stuff.